# How to use data from entity Raw SQL query in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I will state up front I am still very new to asp.net core and entity framework but I am familiar with ADO and recordset which it seems entity framework is built from. I am struggling to use entity framework because I am able to run the query but I am not sure how to use the results and most help docs I see online only discuss the procedures and methods and not how to use the results. I am building login functionality on my site and have developed the following code to query DB in my UserAccount table. FOr this login I really only want the Username, Password, and the ID however I have multiple fields in this table that I dont need for this aspect. I come from using ADO and recordsets so really I just prefer to use raw sql and determine what i want to do with those results and not bind them to some objects which it seems entity framework does for the most part. I do liek the ease of use of the entity framework and using parameters though so I prefer to just go this route (not sure if this is bad practice or not). Everything works great except when I add ToList it starts to say error "InvalidOperationException: The required column 'AccessLevel' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation." I am not even tryign to use that field in the query so not sure why that is even coming up and I am using a rawsql query method so why is it trying to see what I have in the model for that table? Lastly, this shoudl return a single record in which case I want to pull the password value from that record field similar to how i use to do in ADO as you will see in my passwordhash verification but I cannot figure out how to even pull that from the query result. Thanks for any help on this as I am getting a headache trying to learn this stuff!!

```
               var UserResults = _context.UserAccounts.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT USERACCOUNT.USERNAME, USERACCOUNT.PASSWORD, USERACCOUNT.ID,USERACCOUNT.ACCESS_LEVEL FROM DBO.USERACCOUNT WHERE USERACCOUNT.USERNAME={UserName}");

            if (UserResults.Count() == 1) //if we have more than 1 result we have security issue so do not allow login
            {
                var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<string>();
                var hashedPassword = passwordHasher.HashPassword(null, Password);

                var testResults = UserResults.ToList();

                if (passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(null, hashedPassword, THIS SHOULD BE VALUE FROM DB RIGHT HERE!!!) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName)
                };
```

My DBContext is as follows:

```
public partial class LoginDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }

    public LoginDBContext(DbContextOptions<LoginDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>(entity =>
        {
            //entity.ToTable("UserAccount");
            entity.HasNoKey();

            //entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            //    .HasMaxLength(50)
            //    .IsUnicode(false);

            //entity.Property(e => e.Username)
            //    .HasMaxLength(50)
            //    .IsUnicode(false);
            //entity.Property(e => e.Password)
            //    .HasMaxLength(50)
            //    .IsUnicode(false);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load all columns of the user table you can return anonymous object with properties you need or create a class for the columns you need and return it.

```
var users = _context.UserAccounts
    .Where(a => a.UserName == UserName)
    .Select(a => new { a.Id, a.UserName, a.Password })
    .ToArray();

if (users.Length == 1)
{
    var user = users.First();
    if (passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(null, hashedPassword, user.Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
    {
        // ... your magic
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are not even using the fromsqlinterpolated()? Is there a way to do this with the raw sql such as my code?

Comment: `FromRowSql` expect to return an entity so it requires that all columns are provided. You said _I am struggling to use entity framework_ - you do because you not using it as what it was designed for. Usage of `FromRawSql` is provided only for "exceptional" cases. If you are not going to use statically typed queries, then your struggle will continue - look for some other ORM frameworks ;)

Comment: You are absolutely right I should probably force myself to keep using it to learn it. I will adapt my code to wha tyou put but to understand further why UserAccount would even work do I need to adjust my DBContext file at all from what I have above. I commented out ToTable("UserAccount") but I am assuming I should use that to create the link so it knows the table? Also, do you typically create a DBContext in the same file for every table (Ie, modelBuilder.Entity<TableName> for each table in one file).

Comment: EF will use entity type name as a table name by default, use `ToTable('name")` when table and type names are different. You can configure multiple tables in one DbContext in one file.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. I guess ModelBuilder is really isnt necessary for me then in this case since its all identical. Just curious of you opinion on this. If I am very familiar with SQL and have used ADO quite often in VBA projects, would you think I would be better suited using ADO.NET for an application to communicate with a database or do you think entity framework is probably much better to force to learn from scratch?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88, if you want to learn something new try EF, with ADO.NET after sometime you will realise that you are building custom "ORM" to make work with sql easier with less possible errors ;)

Comment: With ADO.NET you will need to create `SqlConnection` and want to keep it somewhere in one place so it easier to maintain. You will prefer to retrieve data into well structured and statically typed objects with ability to use intellisense, instead of "dynamic" data from `DataTable`. EF provides all of this, so all ways to improve your ADO.NET code will lead you to some kind of ORM framework. Check other ORM frameworks, there are few lightweight options.